# Key mappings in RealVNC client

Tags: vnc, vnc-viewer, vnc-server

I am using RealVNC viewer on Windows. I sometimes find it very difficult to shift from VNC to Windows. I have to use <kbd>F8</kbd> -> Minimize and then <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>. I wish I had more flexibility. Can the following key combinations be somehow enabled?

1. <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> -> I see my Windows desktop.
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> switches between VNC and Windows applications.
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> switches between VNC subwindows.

Comment: ctrl+tab usually means switching between documents inside an MRU window, or I.E. tabs for that matter...

Answer (score 9):

I found two solutions:

1 (from: http://www.realvnc.com/products/viewerplus/1.0/docs/af1069655.html)

> Configuring your keyboard
>
> By default, and with the exception of CTRL-ALT-DELETE and the function
>   key used to open the shortcut menu, key presses affect the host
>   computer and not the client. To reverse this behavior for the
>   application-level keys listed below, turn off Pass special keys
>   directly to VNC Server. Note this property is on the Inputs tab.
>
> Affected keys/combinations: WINDOWS (also known as START), PRINT
>   SCREEN, ALT-TAB, ALT-ESCAPE, CTRL-ESCAPE.

2 (from: http://www.physnet.uni-hamburg.de/physnet/vnc/winvncviewer.html)

> Keystrokes such as Ctrl-Esc and Alt-Tab may be interpreted at the
>   local (viewer) machine.  If you want to send them to the remote
>   machine, you can use the options on the viewer menu to send individual
>   Ctrl-down, Ctrl-up, Alt-down and Alt-up keystrokes.  For example, to
>   type Ctrl-Esc on the remote machine, send Ctrl-down using the menu,
>   press Esc, and then send Ctrl-up (or just tap the Ctrl key) to release
>   the Ctrl key at the remote end.

Comment: I didn't get your second solution! It however needs mouse interaction right? You can't do it using keyboard shortcut. If you have to use mouse intervention then we could switch the windows using mouse itself

Answer (score 5):

I am running the Gnome Desktop on the VNC Server, so I followed these steps to implement [the two solutions recommended by user1403360](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10845563):

1. Turn off Viewer -> Options -> Inputs -> "Pass special keys directly to VNC Server" (i.e. parameter SendSpecialKeys=FALSE)

   Alt+Tab will now switch between Windows applications
2. In Gnome Desktop -> Preferences -> KeyboardShortcuts, change "Move between windows using a popup window" => Ctrl+Tab

   Ctrl+Tab will now switch between VNC sub-windows

Comment: In the current version of RealVNC, the procedure is File/Properties/Expert/SendSpecialKeys/False.  This works for Windows key, PrtScn, Alt-Tab, Alt-Esc and Ctrl-Esc.